# Quarto not recognizing code-generated headers in TOC

Tags: python, quarto

Sometimes I need to generate a header from within a code block so it be part of a conditional statement/control flow.

When I add a header using `display()` and `Markdown()` from IPython.display, the header is generated in the document, but not included in the table of contents (TOC).

````
---
title: "Test"
toc: true
format: html
---

```{python}
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
```

```{python}
for i in range(3):
    display(Markdown(f'''## Header {i}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in at in sed nibh. Neque dignissim 
    ad imperdiet urna urna. In id erat aliquam, dolor ut odio. 
    Congue at, non justo fermentum urna suscipit ad torquent posuere.'''))
```
````

I also tried modifying the example code from the [Quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html), which is as follows:

````
```{python}
#| echo: false
#| output: asis

print("# Heading 1\n")
print("## Heading 2\n")
```
````

In my example, it becomes:

````
```{python}
#| echo: false
#| output: asis

for i in range(3):
    print("## Heading using print() \n")
    display(Markdown('''
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in at in sed nibh. Neque dignissim 
    ad imperdiet urna urna. In id erat aliquam, dolor ut odio. 
    Congue at, non justo fermentum urna suscipit ad torquent posuere.'''))

```
````

Using the chunk option, `#| output: asis` does cause the headers to be included in the TOC, which is good, but the headers are printed one after another and then all of the other text is printed. So it's out of order in the rendered document.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was use parts of each attempt from the question:

- Use the `#| output: asis` chunk option
- Use `display(Markdown('\n## Your header name')`
  Note: Adding the newline before the header is important if you are including multiple headers within code. Otherwise, it's possible any header after the first one will render as regular text and not be included in the table of contents, especially if a plot immediately precedes the next header.

  ````
  ---
  title: "Test"
  toc: true
  format: html
  ---

  ```{python}
  from IPython.display import display, Markdown
  ```

  ```{python}
  #| echo: false
  #| output: asis

  for i in range(3):
      display(Markdown(f'''\n## Header {i}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in at in sed nibh. Neque dignissim 
      ad imperdiet urna urna. In id erat aliquam, dolor ut odio. 
      Congue at, non justo fermentum urna suscipit ad torquent posuere.'''))

  ```
  ````